# Android Download Manager giving 400 'placeholder' error in androidX kotlin

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download some file using android download manager, it always gives 400 error, and download unsuccessful message.

```
fun DownloadData(uri: Uri): Long {

    val downloadReference: Long

    downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
    //Setting title of request
    request.setTitle("Test Download")
    //Setting description of request
    request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.")
    //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this@MainActivity, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "AndroidTutorialPoint.mp3")
    //Enqueue download and save the referenceId
    downloadReference = downloadManager!!.enqueue(request)
    return downloadReference
}
```

I am calling above function by

```
val uri = Uri.parse("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1920_18MG.mp4")
downloadId = DownloadData(uri)
```

unable to understand where am i going wrong? the same code works in API level 26, it stopped working after migrating to androidx, and api 29

EDIT: it doesnt work on API level 28 and later irrespective of androidX, shows download unsuccessful

Comment: Hi! Unless I am mistaken, that code does not use any AndroidX code. Are you sure it has to do with AndroidX and not only API Level? Does it work if you keep AndroidX changes but only change API Level?

Comment: not sure, i did 3 things, updating the api, migrating to androidx, and converting the code to Kotlin, probably issue of the latest API or kotlin,

Comment: See what happens if you only do one of the changes. That way you can figure out what change is causing you trouble.

Comment: apperently its API, it works fine till API level 27, even without androidX it shows download unsuccessful when i change the target sdk to 28 or above.
any guess what might be wrong here